# PHP form validation generating static texts

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

So I'm using Codeigniter and want to learn about it, just wondering how form_validation code works?

```
$data['title'] = 'Create Post';

$this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Title', 'required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('body', 'Body', 'required');

if($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE){
    $this->load->view('templates/header');
    $this->load->view('posts/create', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
} else {
    $this->post_model->create_post();
    redirect('posts');
}
```

Because when I input an empty field in a textbox or trigger the validation error it auto generates "The Title field is required" and "The Body field is required." is it part of the library?

Answer (score 1):

I have attached an example of how validation work in CI and example

https://www.guru99.com/codeigniter-form-validation.html

In your code use

> "==" insted of "==="

in IF condition, Because "===" checks datatype also, but here you are checking whether the condition is TRUE or FALSE only.